# Case in Where Clause Issue

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I'm trying to write a `WHERE` clause that captures a certain set of parameters for one instance and another for a different instance.

Right now I wrote up something like this:

```
Where 
    s.ProjectID=110 
    and wfseg.SiteEventGroupID=3 
    and wfse.EventStatusID in (1,2)
    CASE WHEN cf.PaperDocumentTypeID <> 1 
      THEN CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014'  
      ELSE CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014' AND CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) ='09/25/2014'  
    END
```

Pretty much if the PaperDocumentType is not 1 then it should show up with the parameters `CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014'` if the document is in 1 then it should show up following two parameters `CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014' AND CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) ='09/25/2014'`

So I'm getting errors before I run it - not sure how I should rewrite for it to run properly.

Answer (score 3):

It's `CASE WHEN`, not `CASE WHERE`.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try

```
Where 
    s.ProjectID = 110  and 
    wfseg.SiteEventGroupID = 3 and 
    wfse.EventStatusID in (1,2) and

   CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = @parameter and
   CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) = (case when whencf.PaperDocumentTypeID <> 1  then @parameter else CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE)END)
```

Comment: Not sure what the parameter would entail?

Comment: replace Parameter with the date you want like the example you gave or do DECLARE @parameter DATETIME = '2014-09-25' before the query

Answer (score 1):

first, it would base a CASE WHEN, not CASE WHERE.  In addition, when doing a query on a date that is CAST() to a date from a full date time will prevent any such index from being optimized that has the date field.

To also simplify your case when clause, since the cast() is the same date regardless, it could be shortened to

```
 s.ProjectID=110 
    and wfseg.SiteEventGroupID=3 
    and wfse.EventStatusID in (1,2)
    and CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014'
    and (    cf.PaperDocumentTypeID = 1 
        OR ( cf.PaperDocumentTypeID <> 1  and CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) ='09/25/2014' ))
```

For not doing the casting, you could do...

```
    and cf.DateUploaded >= '2014-09-25' and cf.DateUploaded < '2014-09-26'
```

This way, it gets all time for 9/25 up to 11:59:59pm.  A bit longer, but is better if a date is part of an index.

Answer (score 1):

The format of a case does not have the word 'WHERE'.  ([Link To MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case))

```
CASE  cf.PaperDocumentTypeID <> 1
THEN  CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014'  
ELSE  CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014' AND CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) ='09/25/2014'
END
```

You can also use the 'WHEN' clause to make the structure more like a 'C' switch like this:

```
CASE cf.PaperDocumentTypeID
WHEN 1 THEN CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014' AND CAST(cr.CheckDate as DATE) ='09/25/2014'
WHEN 2 THEN  . . . 
WHEN 3 THEN  . . . 
ELSE CAST(cf.DateUploaded as DATE) = '09/25/2014'  
END
```

Second, I believe MySQL dates are in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', but it may be localization specific so I'm not 100% certain.  Also, don't forget another way to produce dates is from the *DATE()* function.  I'm not certain which is more efficient CASE() or DATE(). 
Example:

```
DATE(cf.DateUploaded) = '2014-09-25'
```

Comment: Yep - edited the original to be WHEN but the actual query (without me editing it to be concise with my issue) has WHEN.  Also I'm using T-SQL not MYSql

Comment: But it's fairly similar (what you've given) so I'll give it a try (but the date shouldn't be an issue)